# Including a view as a result of a helper function

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, include, load

I am writing a helper function to share the load of a view, as it can be called a lot of times on certain pages. The only problem is that it only works sometimes, but all the relevant files are there and no error message is generated by Code Igniter. Here is the view that calls the function:

```
        <div id="newProducts" class="floatLeft">
        <div class="titleBar">
            <h4>New Product Arrivals</h4>
        </div>
<?php foreach($newProducts as $product) :
        loadshareProductPreview($product);
endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the function so far:

```
function loadShareProductPreview($product)
{

$time = microtime(true);

if($time % 3 == 0)
{

    include("/home/client/library/application/views/widgets/productPreview.php");

}
elseif($time % 3 == 1)
{

    include("/home/client/library/application/views/widgets/productPreviewLS1.php");

}
elseif($time % 3 == 2)
{

    include("/home/client/library/application/views/widgets/productPreviewLS2.php");

}

}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to load all the time?

Comment: Why don't you load views instead of includes : $this->load->view('/widgets/productPreviewLS2.php') .... ?

Comment: $this doesn't work when it is called from a helper function as they're not in OOPHP

Comment: then use $ci = &get_instance(); $ci->load->view() in your loadshareproduct function

Comment: Why is there a `$product` parameter if you don't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function to replace the incude() after following advice in the comments. Here is the code:

```
<?php
function loadShareProductPreview($product)
{

    $time = microtime(true);

    if($time % 3 == 0)
    {

        load_view("widgets/productPreview", $product);

    }
    elseif($time % 3 == 1)
    {

        load_view("widgets/productPreviewLS1", $product);

    }
    elseif($time % 3 == 2)
    {

        load_view("widgets/productPreviewLS2", $product);

    }

}

function load_view($view, $vars = '', $return = FALSE)
{

  $CI =& get_instance();
  return $CI->load->view($view, $vars, $return);
}
```